# Flask Restful add resource parameters

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am looking to pass an object instance as a parameter into a [Flask-RESTfull](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) Resource.

Here is my setup:

```
# in main.py
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api
from bar import Bar
from foo import views

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

my_bar = Bar()

api.add_resource(views.ApiPage, "/api/my/end/point/")
```

Then in views.py I have the resource set up as follows:

```
# In views.py
from flask.ext.restful import Resource

class ApiPage(Resource):
    def get(self):
        serialized = str(my_bar)
        return serialized
```

So the issue that I am having is that I need to pass my instance of `Bar()` into the api resource. Is there any way to pass it in through the `add_resource` method like `api.add_resource(views.ApiPage, "/api/my/end/point/", instance=bar)`?

Comment: You can override the __init__ of ApiPage.

Comment: I don't believe that overriding ApiPage would work since `add_resource` takes a class reference, rather than a class instance.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Since version 0.3.3 (released May 22, 2015), `add_resource()` is able to pass parameters to your `Resource` constructor.

Following the original example, here is the `views.py`:

```
from flask.ext.restful import Resource

class ApiPage(Resource):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def get(self):
        serialized = str(my_bar)
        return serialized
```

And the relevant code for `main.py`:

```
# ...
my_bar = Bar()
api.add_resource(views.ApiPage, '/api/my/end/point/',
                 resource_class_kwargs={'bar': my_bar})
```

Answer (score 7):

In version 0.3.5 [documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/intermediate-usage.html#passing-constructor-parameters-into-resources) you can do it this way

```
# in main.py
...
my_bar = Bar()
api.add_resource(views.ApiPage, '/api/my/end/point/',
             resource_class_kwargs={'my_bar': my_bar})
```

pass your object in the `add_resource` method and use it in the resource init method

and in your class init

```
class ApiPage(Resource):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.my_bar= kwargs['my_bar']
```

Comment: you saved me, a green hand 4 python.

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with the same problem I found you can use `add_url_rule` coupled with `as_view`

So in your case I guess the code would be something like

```
class ApiPage(Resource):
    def __init__(self, bar=None)
        self.__my_bar=bar

    def get(self):
        serialized = str(self.__my_bar)
        return serialized

my_bar = Bar()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.add_url_rule('/api/my/end/point/', bar=my_bar)

api = Api(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the [documentation](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#flask.ext.restful.Api.add_resource) such thing can not be done at this level. One way to circumvent this issue would be to put the initialisation of `Bar` inside another module, then fetch the instance through an import in your views module.